# AWK to compare columns in file1 to file2

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a simple problem but have not been able to solve. I want to compare columns 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 of `File1` to the same columns of `File2` and if they match then add `Column1` of `File2` to `Column7` of `File1`.

I have tried `awk NR == FNR`-based solutions from previously posted similar issues but have not been able to adopt to get the corrrect output.

`File1`:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
Genome1 1       1       2       1       2
Genome2 1       1       2       1       2
Genome3 1       2       2       1       2
```

`File2`:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
Profile1 1       1       2       1       2
Profile2 1       2       2       1       2
Profile3 1       3       2       1       2
```

Expected results:

```
File1
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7
Genome1 1       1       2       1       2       Profile1
Genome2 1       1       2       1       2       Profile1
Genome3 1       2       2       1       2       Profile2
```

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: This sounds more like a StackOverflow question than an AskUbuntu question. Perhaps someone could answer your question there?

Answer (score 2):

You need hold all the columns you want to do match on the same columns on second file first then compare each for every line read from your first file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
    if(NR==1) $1="Column7"; file2[$2, $3, $4, $5, $6]=$1; next; };
    (($2, $3, $4, $5, $6) in file2){ print $0, file2[$2, $3, $4, $5, $6];
}' OFS='\t' file2 file1
```

---

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7
Genome1 1       1       2       1       2       Profile1
Genome2 1       1       2       1       2       Profile1
Genome3 1       2       2       1       2       Profile2
```